# strange thing about foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I meet Strange Problem when I use foreignkey in laravel

When I used **unsignedBigInteger** Foreign key work

```html
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

But if I just edit Datatype it to

**$table->*unsignedInteger**('user_id');

** or

**$table->Integer('user_id');**

**Foreign key Not work**

I don't know why this happend

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your id datatype `unsignedInteger` or `Integer` you need first to change the users id datatypes in its migration file to the same data type because of a foreign key must have the same data type between the two columns